# how to actually use the micro ROS messages in a ROS2 node

Tags: ros2, rosserial, serial, ros-humble, custom-message

I have successfully created micro ROS firmware with a subscriber. the subscriber subscribes to topic /joint_angles of type servo2040_uros__msg__JointAngles. Now, how do I include this message type in my ROS2 workspace so that my nodes can actually publish to this topic?

Comment: Are you asking because you can't find information that defines "servo2040_uros__msg__JointAngles"? Or are you asking how to set up and use a publisher?

Comment: Is this your custom interface you're using on the uROS side? You'll have to build and source the same thing in your ROS2 workspace to be able to include it in code.